# Can I use multi wordpress install in single server and same theme?

Tags: wordpress

Can I use multi wordpress install in single server and same theme ?

Suppose I bought one theme, but I want to use it multiple time in same server but different subdomain ex:

www.xxx.com => apply red style

www.a.xxx.com => apply yellow style

www.b.xxx.com => apply orange style

all wordpress using same theme but different content data and style. Only user database are sharing together.

Can I do this on Wordpress ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Yes, this is exactly what a multi site is for.

Comment: Can u guild me how to do this ? any plugin require or some set up ? Thanks

Comment: @rnevius is correct, when in doubt consult the codex. There is no better guide to learning Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible.

Simply Create a sub domain from Main Panel. 
like a.xxx.com it will create a directory in Web Space(File Manager)

Now Open File Manger public_html/a.xxx.com(or what ever named you choose for the directory)

Simply install new wordpress with same theme & correspondingly create new database for your New subdomain.

Repeat step for more Website you want.

Finally done :)

or Try this - http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network